# Date locked image change

Tags: javascript

I’m trying to make a simple Advent calendar.
Load a background image. Overlay 24 numbered images ontop of that.
When the overlaid images are clicked, they should change to a transparent image, revealing the background image below. But only if it has reached that date.

Here’s the mess of code I have.

It should check date validity, then either show the alert, or switch the clicked image to a transparent one.
How many mistakes have I made?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> test calendar</title>
    <script>
        function getID(oObject) {
            var ih = oObject.id;
        }
    </script>

    <script>
        function dooropen(door) {
            today = new Date();
            daynow = today.getDate();
            monthnow = today.getMonth();

            if (monthnow != 11 && monthnow != 0) {
                alert("Is it Advent yet? NO. No it isn't Please come back then.");
                return false;
            }

            if (daynow == door - 1) {
                alert("A little bit early I'm afraid honey. Come back tomorrow to see what's behind that door!");
                return false;
            }

            if (door > daynow) {
                alert("Now you\'re just taking the piss. You\'ll have to wait " +
                    (door - daynow) + " days before that door's available!");
                return false;
            }

            var ih = oObject.id;
            image = document.getElementById(ih);
            image.src = "clock2.png";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<style>
    body {
        background-image: url(img_1.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
</style>
<body>
       <img id="imgDisp1" href="#" src="clock.png" onclick="getID(this); dooropen(1);">
<img id="imgDisp2" href="#" src="clock.png" onclick="getID(this); dooropen(2);">
<img id="imgDisp3" href="#" src="clock.png" onclick="getID(this); dooropen(3);">
<img id="imgDisp4" href="#" src="clock.png" onclick="getID(this); dooropen(4);">
<img id="imgDisp5" href="#" src="clock.png" onclick="getID(this); dooropen(5);">
```

Comment: Why not just remove the image if user clicks on it?

Comment: That'll do just fine. But I still have no idea how. I need replace/delete to be the default action of the dooropen function. So it only happens after the right date. return false should prevent the default action. What am I missing?

Comment: I got it working. @Wirzi Thanks for the formatting. I added another variable to the door open function and passed the image id along with that. Then passed it to the changeImage function after the date checking.